# What encoding is this: <U+043B><U+043E><U+0448><U+0430><U+0434><U+044C>

Tags: character-encoding

I have tried a few online encoding detectors without success. The general format is `<U+XXXY>` where `X` is numeric and `Y` is alphabetical. I know the content when decoded should be Cyrillic however I am struggling to find a decoder that I can use.

I need to know the name of the encoding. Also, if anyone knows an online decoder then that would be awesome!

Thanks in advance and apologies if the answer is easily googleable. I have failed in my searches.

Comment: why the downvote? I know the title is a bit off but I am pretty sure I am on guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it appears to be a derivative of U+hex encoded. Don't know what the angle brackets are but substituting them out and using the U+hex decoder [here](https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/) seems to get the right response. I still don't know what this decoding is called so happy to accept a more thorough answer.

Comment: Yup, seems that's pretty much it. Hexadecimal Unicode code points in brackets. What's returning that data to you?

Comment: To get from some complete garbage to the above the process (I believe - some of it is a black box) is as follows. Javascript -> encodeURI -> R -> URLdecode -> Encoding(UTF-8). We only have control over the final 3 steps.